# How to embed plugin in android chrome browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-nativeclient, ppapi

I need to develop ppapi plugin and include it into build of android chromium. Now, I know how to build apk file from chromium source code. But I don’t know how to make APK file with preinstalled plugin. I found ppapi plugin sample

```
src/native_client_sdk/src/getting_started/part1/
```

and complied it, but I don’t know where I must place these files in sources of android chromium to build them together?

Comment: I, probably, found how to make(run make utility, thanks to captain obvious:)) pexe file from plugin's source files. Maybe solution is to place this file in some out/Release subdirectory to include it in release apk file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this help entry](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2710225?hl=en),

> Chrome for Android doesn't support plug-ins, including Flash.

Comment: I know that. But there is still possibility to enable plugins(ppapi) when run build from source code.

Comment: Dmitry, check this link https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/google-to-release-ppapi-flash-android-t3235503